Access to S3 in root and child account through roles
We have a root AWS account and a child account for another application called prod.
I want to give IAM users Full S3 Access to all the buckets in both the root account and the prod account.
In order to achieve this,
I have created a role in the prod account with the following policies:

AmazonS3FullAccess (AWS Managed Policy)
An Inline Policy:

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

In the Trust Relationship for this role, I have the set the following trust relationship, so that users from the root account can access the buckets in the prod account.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<root_account_id>:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Now, In the root account, I have attached the following policy to the user through a Group:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::<prod_account_id>:role/ProdS3FullAccessRole"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

In addition, the AmazonS3FullAccess policy has been attached so that the users have full access to S3 in the root account.
When the user uses their Access Key and Secret Access Key to download files from a bucket in the root account, they get an Access Denied error. I can confirm that there is no Deny statement blocking any access to any bucket nor any bucket level policy.
I am unable to find out what is wrong with the set up.
As suggested in docs, I have also tried setting up a bucket policy in the root account, to grant access to a bucket for the Prod access role that gets assumed by the user. The user still gets an Access Denied error on trying to use the access keys to perform operations on a root S3 bucket, generated for their IAM user.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<prod_account_id>:role/ProdS3FullAccessRole"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"
        }
    ]
}

The user is not even trying to assume the role. They are just using their access key and secret access key in the root account to access a bucket in the root account itself as follows:
 s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                      aws_access_key_id='<access_key_id>',
                      aws_secret_access_key='<secret_access_key>',
                      region_name='<reg>')

 # List objects in the S3 bucket with the specified prefix
 response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix)

This operation is throwing an AccessDenied error.
How do I provide access to users to S3 in both the Root and Child account?
I have followed the setup for AccountA and AccountC mentioned in this example in the AWS Docs
I'd really appreciate some help.
Thank you in advance.
-- EDIT --
I have also noticed that a Policy has been attached to Force the User to set up MFA for the Prod account. On detaching this policy, the access keys for the root account as well as the assumed role work fine. When I attach this policy, the operations start throwing an AccessDenied error.
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowViewAccountInfo",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnPasswords",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ChangePassword",
                "iam:GetUser"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnAccessKeys",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateAccessKey",
                "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys",
                "iam:UpdateAccessKey",
                "iam:GetAccessKeyLastUsed"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnSigningCertificates",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeleteSigningCertificate",
                "iam:ListSigningCertificates",
                "iam:UpdateSigningCertificate",
                "iam:UploadSigningCertificate"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnSSHPublicKeys",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeleteSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:GetSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
                "iam:UpdateSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:UploadSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnGitCredentials",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:DeleteServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
                "iam:ResetServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:UpdateServiceSpecificCredential"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnVirtualMFADevice",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:mfa/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnUserMFA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAllExceptListedIfNoMFA",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:GetUser",
                "iam:GetMFADevice",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
                "sts:GetSessionToken"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


You have two options: Either users need to Assume the role in the root account and then use the returned credentials to access the root bucket, or you can add a Bucket Policy on the root bucket that grants access to specific IAM entities in the child account. Which method do you wish to use?

I'd prefer going with the Assume role route. However, getting an Access Denied error in accessing buckets in the root account as well as the prod account. I have setup Trust relationship as mentioned above. I really don't understand what's missing.

The error is as follows:
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::<root_account_id>:user/ is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<prod_account_id>:role/ProdS3FullAccessRole
I have checked the policies and trust relationship multiple times, something still seems to be missing.

I have figured out the problem. On changing the Deny policy to BoolIfExists to Bool, the access keys work fine.
