Getting AccessDenied when trying to use PutObjectCommand from @aws-sdk/client-s3
I'm trying to upload file to an S3 bucket. This is part of my postbuild script.
Until 2 weeks ago it was working fine, then suddenly I started getting AccessDenied error.
I have generated new Access Key as well, and the key and secret values are correct.
The IAM user I am using has Full S3 access. I have cross checked this multiple times as well.
I can upload files from the AWS S3 GUI correctly. But when I try to do it in Node using @aws-sdk/client-s3. It throws an error. Region and bucket_name are correct as well.
I've attached the code. The error gets thrown at s3Client.send().
const { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const REGION = "us-east-1";
const bucket_name = 'bucket_name';
const access_key = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID;
const access_secret = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;

const s3Client = new S3Client({ credentials: { accessKeyId: access_key, secretAccessKey: access_secret }, region: REGION });

const data = await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand({
          Bucket: bucket_name,
          Key: "test.txt",
          Body: "hello"
        })  
        );

Error I get looks like this:
AccessDenied: Access Denied
    ...
 {
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 403,
    requestId: '...',
    extendedRequestId: '...',
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  Code: 'AccessDenied',
  RequestId: '...',
  HostId: '...'


Is it the same bucket? Bucket is owned by you or different user/account?
Can you share your IAM policy? Also please check your iam policy access suing simulator https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/
Using the same access key/id　Can you do the same using AWS CLI ?
Verify that you're using the correct IAM user or role. You can verify your IAM user or role by checking the upper-right corner of the AWS Management Console or by using the aws sts get-caller-identity command.

There could be many reasons bucket policy with explicit deny. You need to give more details

Thanks @JatinMehrotra! I resolved the issue by following the comments from this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78334242/access-to-s3-in-root-and-child-account-through-roles.
